# excel data splitting/assigning

Tags: excel, vba

I have been given an input file in excel that just goes down column "M2" down. Put the input file looks like this:

```
ru_utime     0.060              
ru_stime     0.140              
ru_maxrss    0                          
ru_ixrss     0                          
ru_ismrss    0                          
ru_idrss     0                          
ru_isrss     0                          
ru_minflt    4124                       
ru_majflt    0                          
ru_nswap     0                          
ru_inblock   0                          
ru_oublock   0                          
ru_msgsnd    0                          
ru_msgrcv    0                          
ru_nsignals  0                          
ru_nvcsw     47174                      
ru_nivcsw    4347                       
==================================================
```

then it repeats about 1000+ times in the same format

as you can see it has two bits of information in the same column then the next bunch is seperated by ===
what I want to do is ignore the heading for each bit and take the information on the right and move them to different columns underneath eachother.

what I want to do is read down the file and put all the information under like ru_utime : **0.060** under a different column accross

so all the data is in "M2" down, i want to take the corresponding titles information and move them to like S2, T2, U2 for each one then when it hits ======= do it for the next underneath it. if that makes any sense to anyone i would really appreciate the help.

aim is to automate the move over on a click of a button, thanks

added:

```
Sub incorperate()
sn = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1)), "|"), String(62, "=") & "|")
With Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion
st = .Rows(1).Offset(.Rows.Count).Resize(UBound(sn) + 1)
End With

For j = 0 To UBound(sn)
sq = Split(sn(j), "|")
For jj = 0 To UBound(sq) - 1
  st(j + 1, jj + 1) = Split(sq(jj))(UBound(Split(Trim(sq(jj)))))
Next
Next

Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(st), UBound(st, 2)) = st
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that can be easily achieved. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've been looking but I don't know how to say anything after the heading move to column t then move all headings information accross until you hit ==== then increment and do again

Comment: Want to give it a try using a different method (There are many ways)? Use `.Find` and `.FindNext` to search for "======= " and then setting your ranges to be copied as you want. You can then use a macro to record how `Copy` and `Pastespecial - Transpose` works? Combining the two piece of code will give you what you want. For `.Find` and `.FindNext`, see this link http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Comment: hey sid, sorry i didnt reply before i left for the weekend, due to restrictions here I cant go on wordpress to look, but I have added some code above that should take information from sheet to in that format and put it into sheet 1 in the region way i wanted it, it started working now suddenly stopped, any ideas? Subscript out of range on the split line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub move()
Dim x, y(), i&, j&, k&, s

x = Range("S1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
        .Item(x(1, i)) = i
    Next i

    x = Application.Trim(Range("M2", Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp)).Value)
    ReDim y(1 To UBound(x), 1 To .Count): j = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(x)
        If InStr(x(i, 1), "==") = 0 Then
            s = Split(x(i, 1))
            If .Exists(s(0)) Then
                k = .Item(s(0)): y(j, k) = s(UBound(s))
            End If
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

[s2].Resize(j, UBound(y, 2)).Value = y()
End Sub
```